# Combining String to construct Enum value

Tags: java, enums

Just wanted to know if this is a good practice on constructing enum values.

```
public enum SomeConstant{


     ENUM_ONE("this is my "),
     ENUM_TWO(ENUM_ONE.getSomeConstant() + " enum");

     private final String constant;

     private SomeConstant(String constant){
         this.constant = constant;
     }

     private String getSomeConstant(){
         return constant;
     }


}
```

Comment: I'm curious: why would you desire to do this?

Comment: One could argue it is easier to maintain (as it reuses code), but that's such a localized reuse that I actually think it is clearer (more maintainable) if the `String`s are repeated.